# Assumptions about list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, assumptions

I am trying to simplify some expressions using assumptions and got an inconsistent behavior of *Mathematica* 9 when working with indexed variables. Consider

```
Assuming[Subscript[x,_] ∈ Reals, Refine[Im[Subscript[x, 10]]]]
```

> 0

```
Assuming[Subscript[x,_] ∈ Reals && Subscript[x,_] > 0, Refine[Sign[Subscript[x,10]]]]
```

> ```
> Sign[Subscript[x, 10]]
> ```

```
Assuming[Subscript[x,10] > 0, Refine[Sign[Subscript[x,10]]]]
```

> 1

It appears that assumptions about an indexed variable being real work, but assumptions about the positivity of an indexed variable seem not to work.

Comment: Have you tried `Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, Refine[Im[x]]]
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && x > 0, Refine[Sign[x]]]
Assuming[x > 0, Refine[Sign[x]]]`?

Comment: This works as expected. My problem is that assumptions on patterns can only work for domains.

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* `Assuming` that supports general patterns, but [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Element.html).  This explains why

```
Assuming[x > 0, Refine@Sign[x]]
```

gives 1, while

```
Assuming[x[_] > 0, Refine@Sign[ x[1] ]]
```

does not.

Comment: Just a note: seems like `Element` only supports patterns with domains such as `Reals`, not regions such as `Interval`.  Not directly relevant to this question, but in case someone finds this later on...

Comment: @ChrisK That's not obvious at all, but reading under Details on the Element doc page makes it clear why it's so.