# Assumptions about indexed variables

Tags: pattern-matching, vector, core-language, argument-patterns, indexed-variable

I am interested in the most efficient way to impose assumptions on indexed variables. In the following stylized problem, the following code

```
a := f[1] > 0 && f[2] > 0 && f[1] < 1 && f[2] < 1 && f[1] + f[2]== 1;
Simplify[f[1] + f[2] <= 0, a]
```

Obviously returns false. Now I want to impose assumptions in a "more general" way. I have tried many different ways and didn't find a convincing solution.

1.) The function/pattern approach.

```
a := f[i_Integer] > 0 && f[i_Integer] < 1;
Simplify[f[1] + f[2] <= 0, a]
```

Returns the input. This is really surprising since the assumptions seem to work for a similar example,

```
a := f[i_Integer] > 0 && f[i_Integer] < 1;
Simplify[f[1]<= 0, a]
```

again, returning false. This behavior seems to be, if not wrong, then at least very annoying. Even stranger

```
a := f[i_Integer] > 0 && f[i_Integer] < 1;
Simplify[f[1]<0, a]
```

again (???) returns the input.

From a mathematical standpoint, this is complete nonsense. I would like to work with conditionals in the assumptions of the form
`f[x_Integer /; x < 10]<0` or `f[x_,y_]<=1/2/; x < y`, a flexible approach is, therefore necessary. Using patterns in Assumptions seems to be somehow problematic, e.g. ([$Assumptions = _ ∈ Reals results in incorrect simplification of ConjugateTranspose[..]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273660/assumptions-%e2%88%88-reals-results-in-incorrect-simplification-of-conjugatetranspo/273665#273665)).

How can I impose such variable assumptions in an efficient way?

Should I work with subscripts? This seems to be problematic, as demonstrated here:([Assumptions about list elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32113/assumptions-about-list-elements)). Symbolizing seems a problem, too: ([How to treat indexed variables as Reals? Can they be symbolized?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131778/how-to-treat-indexed-variables-as-reals-can-they-be-symbolized)).

I am also interested in the pros and cons of different ways to work with variable indexes. Is there a universally accepted dominant way?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Clear[a];
a[i_] := f[i] > 0 && f[i] < 1;

With[{i = 3}, Simplify[f[i] > 5, a[i]]]


(*  False  *)
```

??

Comment: Thank you, If I got you right, this approach works by fixing `i` in every evaluation I will use later on. This doesn't seem to be an efficient way to set assumptions for indexed variables - I am interested in specifying assumptions once, and proceeding with what I call "normal coding". My suggestion to impose assumptions in 1.) seems to work partially - what do I miss there?

Comment: @oyy "If I got you right, this approach works by fixing i in every evaluation..." Yes and no. First, you define `a[i]`. This you do once during the session. Second, you use `Simplify` or `Reduce` with the already defined `a[i]`. You may specify the value of `i` and may not. It works also with a symbol there.